# Git Branch vs Working on Master Branch in a Different Working Directory

Tags: git

Let's say you have a project called foo_bar and you're writing some code for some new feature... do a commit... and then do a push to origin. Maybe now you share the link to your project with a few work colleagues. Now let's say you want to work on this some more, but you don't want to mess with your current production code. Why would you create another branch **opposed** to creating another working directory, editing the master branch until you have it the way you want, pushing to origin when it's ready, and then pulling it down in the production repo?

Answer (score 0):

Your alternative method of just editing the master branch directly is fine, nothing wrong with that in itself. You would get the benefit of creating a new branch when you wanted to share your new changes with another colleague who would then also contribute, before then merging back into the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

By creating multiple branches in a single repository and working directory, you don't have to change anything about your development environment when you switch branches: Your working directory might always be `/path/to/myproject` whether you're working on the master branch or a feature branch.

If this isn't important to you, it's perfectly reasonable to clone the repository into another directory and use that as your second branch instead. In fact, Mercurial's documentation explicitly mentions this method of branching, and it works equally well with Git.